# new electrical outlets and switch pop breaker

Tags: electrical

We have a house from the 1960s with armored cable and metal boxes.  I was trying to replace the outlets and a switch in the kitchen so they weren't almond/painted but the new outlets and switch keep causing the breaker to pop. I put the old one back and everything works fine again.  Is there something I am missing on old vs new outlets

Comment: From less than 24 hours ago, a similar issue: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48308/adding-usb-dual-port-charger-receptacle-blows-mains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tab connects the two halves of the duplex outlet. This lets one black/white pair power both halves. In your case, it seems two circuits were sent to the duplex. In order for this to work the tab must be removed. If there are two black wires and two white wires in the box, break the tab between the two silver screws as well and secure one white under each silver screw. If only one white, connect it to either silver screw and leave the tab in place. The green wire, or wires, should be under the green screw.

The switch does not have a tab as it only breaks one circuit. It likely has only two screws, one on each side. Ideally there are two black wires in the box with the switch, one should go under each screw. If there are two white wires in the box, connect them with a wire nut. You can do the same if there are green wires.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, any idea on the switch since there isn't a tab between the top and the bottom?

Comment: Your comment says that the green wire, or wires should be under the ground screw. This implies that it is OK to have more than one wire under a screw, it is NOT. I doubt you meant to imply that so I wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Are you located in Canada? Was the tiny tab broken between the two gold screws on the receptacles?

Comment: Not a unique to Canada wiring practice. Multiwire branch circuits that are split on halves of outlets are also common in the USA, and that's certainly what this sounds like.

Comment: Im in usa, tab is broken on outlets so that must be it.  What exactly is the purpose of that tab?  The switch does not have a tab though and I still had an issue with that

Comment: Obviously it's not unique to Canada, but split wired kitchen counter receptacles are typical there, and not at all typical in the US.

Comment: @DanJ the purpose is to carry current to both halves of the outlet. Sometimes you want one half to be switched, so you add a wire from the switch to only half of the outlet after breaking off the tab. Another use is for multiwire branch circuits, which if you didn't break off the tab would create a short circuit from one phase to the other ... if you're lucky.